# Font family in siunitx package

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I recently stumbled over the `siunitx`-package and I find it quite cool.
Unfortunately I have a big problem with fonts an this package.

My whole document is written with `Latin Modern Roman` or `lmr`, which is a beautiful and well readable font.  Unfortunately any text output by the package is in an other font (see graphic [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMHr3.jpg)).

What should I do, to have the package use `lmr` when writing something?

[image: example]

Here's a part of my preamble:

```
% Set Document Class
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl} 

% Layout & Language Packages & Options
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Graphics Packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% Tables Packages
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Math Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Chemistry Packages
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{mhchem}

% Bibliography Packages
\usepackage[square,super,comma,sort]{natbib}

% New Commands
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{lmr}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmr}
\sisetup{
    detect-family,
    detect-display-math = true 
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you simply write `\usepackage{lmodern}`?

Comment: Well... Good question. I think I didn't remember. But unfortunately this does not solve the issue

Comment: Oh okay, I removed `\renewcommand*\rmdefault{lmr}` and `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmr}`, now it works. But my section headings are written in a non-serif font again. How would you change that correctly?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmr}` changes the `\section{}`-font back to `Latin Modern Roman`, but then the font of the output pf `siunitx` is false again. When deleting the renewcommand, the units are correct, but the `\section{}` is false...

Comment: In a current scrartcl you can use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrartcl}` to get serif headings.

Comment: I think it's the default for `koma-script` classes?. For the section headings font, try something like `setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmdefault}`.  See §3.6 of the documentation.